# ECCN number for Commstudio ActiveX

Tags: activex, sax

I am in stage of getting the export license for my company product, which needs information of all the components/products involved in the implementation of my company product. Regarding Commstudio ActiveX product, my questions are:

1. What is the country of origin for this product?
2. Does this product contain any encryption?
3. Is the product subject to EAR (export administration regulation) or not, if product is USA based? Please explain.
4. What is the ECCN/Export License number for the above mentioned product?

The most important among all is the question number 1 and 4. I already searched the web, and also written an email to Commstudio personnel, but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you really need to contact the manufacturer about directly to make sure you get an accurate answer. From their website it looks like they are US based: http://www.commstudio.com/about/contact